# How to write long z/OS UNIX shell commands in BPXBATCH

Tags: shell, unix, zos, jcl

I'm going to describe my issue as well as possible.

I know in advance that is is possible to type a z/OS shell UNIX command that does not fit on one line using a backslash at the end of the first line. In fact I've tested it in the computer I'm working with and executes well.

For example; in order to do a test I've type ls command as follows:

Firstly without backslash from the command line:

```
ls -la
```

After with backslash also from the command line:

```
ls\
 -la
```

I get the same good results

What I would like to know is how to do the same in a z/OS UNIX shell script in STDIN executed with BPXBATCH.

If I put the command as follows ls -la it executes well; but If I try to break it in two lines it does not work.

May anyone shed light in this issue?.

Many thaks in advance

(Obvioulsy `ls -la` is a very simple example only intended to show the problem I'm facing; real commands are much more larger)

Comment: Sorry; the example command ls\ -la spans two lines; the first line till the backslash. The second line has a blank space plus -la

Comment: In your post above the  '\' is the last charater on the line (OK). When it did not work, did you put a space after de backslash? In that case the bashslash will work on the space, not on the '\n'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this. 
Using BPXBATCH, you want to issue a shell command. Here would be a simple example:

```
//TSTRADMB  JOB  MSGCLASS=X,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),NOTIFY=&SYSUID,REGION=0M
//BPXIT EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,PARM='SH ls -l'
//BPXPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//STDOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//STDERR DD SYSOUT=*
```

This has the desired effect of writing the output of the shell command `ls -l` to stdout. 
But - what if it's a much longer string? Two ways you could go. One would be to write a wrapper script and call it from BPXBATCH (which is what I would do). The other would be to put the PARM across multiple lines, in which case you need to follow JCL rules for continuation (using a + in column 72 works), e.g.

```
//TSTRADMB  JOB  MSGCLASS=X,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),NOTIFY=&SYSUID,REGION=0M
//BPXIT EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,PARM='SH ls -l "/u/tstradm/ThisIsAReallyLongD+
//             irectoryThatCrossesMultipleLines"'
//BPXPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//STDOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//STDERR DD SYSOUT=*
```

The spacing with JCL is truly annoying - so you have to get it right. That + sign has to be in column 72 or you get a JCL error. The start of the next line of text begins in column 16. Start it late and you end up with blanks (which in this case would make a difference).

Comment: Thanks mike; your answer helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: @mike thanks! If I add a third continuation line, in shows me a JCL error. I added the plus sign in column 72 of the first 2. A third line can't be added?

Comment: unfortunately, there is a 100 character limit! That's probably what you are hitting

Answer (score 6):

To pass long commands to BPXBATCH, use the STDPARM DD.

While it is possible to pass *relatively* long commands to BPXBATCH via the PARM parameter on the JCL EXEC statement by using JCL continuation rules, this method is still limited to 100 bytes.

A parameter file passed to BPXBATCH via STDPARM supports parameters (i.e the command) up to 64K in length. The parameter file can be a z/OS-Unix file, a traditional z/OS dataset, or in-stream in the JCL.

For example, place a long command (this sample command is 105 bytes):

```
SH ls -altr /listed_environments/cics/test/pickup/webs/test-portal-v01/src/assets/mixins | grep functions
```

into a z/OS-Unix file at `/u/userid/stdparmfile`

Then execute the command via BPXBATCH by utilizing STDPARM (PATHOPTS must be set to ORDONLY):

```
//USSCMD EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDERR  DD SYSOUT=*
//STDOUT  DD SYSOUT=*
//STDPARM DD PATH='/u/userid/stdparmfile',PATHOPTS=ORDONLY
/*
//
```

Or place the same command into a traditional z/OS dataset (with a sufficient LRECL). Ensure that sequence numbers are removed from the dataset by issuing `UNNUM` and/or `NUMBER OFF` while in ISPF EDIT. Then similarly submit through JCL:

```
//USSCMD EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDERR  DD SYSOUT=*
//STDOUT  DD SYSOUT=*
//STDPARM DD DISP=SHR,DSN=USERID.STDPARM.TEST
/*
//
```

In-stream submission on the STDPARM DD is a bit more restrictive, as a space character is assumed on each line-end. An in-stream command should be fine if it can be broken apart on space-char boundaries to fit within the 80-byte limit for JCL. The sample command we've used here would work like this:

```
//USSCMD EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDERR  DD SYSOUT=*
//STDOUT  DD SYSOUT=*
//STDPARM DD *
SH ls -altr
/listed_environments/cics/test/pickup/webs/test-portal-v01/src/assets/mixins
| grep functions
/*
//
```

But, a command that includes an uninterrupted string of text >80 bytes would likely present challenges for in-stream.

The z/OS 2.3 documentation for STDPARM can be found here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa400/batstdparm.htm

Comment: Many thanks Rich; I've been very busy these last weeks and till today I haven't been able to read and check carefully your answer. I've tested every part of your response and all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In BPXBATCH, you actually want to use '+' as your continuation character for STDIN. BPXBATCH is a TSO command processor so it uses the TSO continuation character and not USS'

Comment: It appears that for some reason PBXBATCH does not honor the continuation characters and includes "+" and "-" into the commands.  But you can just break lines and it will lump all lines together into one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Coming a bit late to the party, but PBXBATCH just concatenates multiple lines into one.  In your case it could look like:

```
//PBXTST   JOB ,MSGLEVEL=(2,0),NOTIFY=&SYSUID.
//DOIT     EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=*
//STDPARM  DD *
SH 
ls
-a
/*
```

Just as a sample with multiple commands,often this would be multiple commands (note the semicolon):

```
//PBXTST   JOB ,MSGLEVEL=(2,0),NOTIFY=&SYSUID.
//DOIT     EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=*
//STDPARM  DD *
SH (
cd somedir;
ls -a
)
/*
```

See this link for reference: https://bit.listserv.ibm-main.narkive.com/LphTazF4/multi-line-stdparm-shell-script-for-bpxbatch